# ag-grid, select individual columns

Tags: ag-grid

I’m learning features of ag-grid.
And there is one particular we need to have – ability to select specific columns using check box on top of all columns and one more check box on top left corner to be able select/unselect all columns.
We do not need highlight (though it’s good if it possible), but just indicate (with the checkbox) what was selected.

If there such built-in functionality or it can be added programmatically?

Comment: I don't think it's built-in, but it sounds possible. You can put whatever you want in column headers (including checkboxes), see [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-header/#gsc.tab=0) and [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#gsc.tab=0). For the highlighting, maybe the `cellClass` [column property](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/#gsc.tab=0) function variant. If you figure it out, you can answer your own question. Or, if you think my comment answers your question sufficiently, let me know and I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I see, it can be part of header template. I think it can be an answer.